# using openpyxl to locate merged cell's current region

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlwings

I'm trying to deal with a workbook, and the tables within the workbook are various, and there are two or more tables within a single worksheet, but all of them have one thing in common, that's they are all starting with a merged cell. So I need to locate the merged cell to locate every single table. I located the merged cells with openpyxl library. what I have to do is to locate the entire tables which cover the located cells.

I learned excel vba and I knew in VBA, current region method would cover the located merged cell's region.
but, it seems there is no current region or so method to be used in openpyxl library, and on the other hand it seems no method to locate merged cells in xlwings library.

what I'm doing is write some code to convert the located merged cell to xlwings object, and use current_region function in xlwings to locate the region that the merged cell is covered. It's so complicated that i was totally confused and got some error when testing.

Is there any possible to locate my tables with openpyxl library or, to locate merged cells with xlwings library?

Can anybody help me?

I'm not good at English, I wish I have described my question clearly.

Thanks

zhou

Answer (score 0):

In xlwings, you can loop over all cells in the workbook to get the addresses of the merged cells.

```
import xlwings as xw

report_file = r"test.xlsx"
wb = xw.Book(report_file)

for sheet in wb.sheets:
    for cell in sheet.used_range:
        if cell.merge_cells == True:
            print(sheet.range(cell.address).merge_area)
```